# Working with Multiple Projects and a Single Team

Tags: azure-devops

We are a small team of around 8 developers and I would like to ask if it is possible to view all work on a single board. We use the kanban board and we are not working in sprints so the Delivery Plan extension is not suitable for us. We want to view all works of all our engineers on different projects on a single kanban board.

I read this article (https://nkdagility.com/one-team-project/) and so far it is working for us. However, it seems that this is really a workaround instead of an actual feature.

I would like to ask if this is still a legit way to do it or VSTS has already improved and maybe provided a solution for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Having used Azure DevOps for a while, I'm now starting to understand that I have been using it wrong all along. The main reason for this is the use of the term "Project" in Azure DevOps and how that is interpreted.

If you follow [Microsoft's definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops):

> A project provides a repository for source code and a place for users to plan, track progress, and collaborate on building software solutions. A project represents a fundamental container where data is stored when added to Azure DevOps.

This doesn't say "a software solution" but it says "software solutions" which suggests you can have multiple software projects within one Azure DevOps "Project".

It wasn't until recently I realised you can have more than one repository inside an Azure DevOps Project.

This means that all the Boards / Sprints etc can share work items across Software Projects.

In fact, this is the Microsoft [default recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops);

> #### When to add another project
>
> In general, we recommend that you use a single project to support your organization or enterprise. A single project minimizes the maintenance of administrative tasks and supports the most optimized / full-flexibility cross-link object experience.

Comment: While this is the correct answer, there are still time you need to work across projects so please up vote on the community request [Single Dashboard for Multiple Projects](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/single-dashboard-for-multiple-projects/365500) and also look at the Marketplace extension [Query Based Boards](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=realdolmen.EdTro-AzureDevOps-Extensions-QueryBasedBoards-Public&targetId=fdc1edee-e433-4373-ac8a-a4f42f8f153f&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList)

Answer (score 5):

One project with multiple repos/build definitions/release definitions/etc would be the "legit way" to do this.

Comment: This is absolutely true but the main thing to understand is the disconnect between a "Software Project" and an Azure DevOps "Project".

Answer (score 5):

For now, VSTS does not support the feature to view all the work items across projects. And there has user voices which suggest this feature, you can vote and follow up:

- [Allow Teams to work over multiple Projects (Teams at the Collection level in Visual Studio Online)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365469/allow-teams-to-work-over-multiple-projects-teams-a.html)

And except [using Team Project to rule them together](https://nkdagility.com/one-team-project/) (as you linked), there has below options which may help for part of situations:

#### Option 1: query work items across projects

In a project Queries Tab -> create a new query -> select the option Query across projects -> specify the clauses you want to query -> Save query -> Run query.

[image]

Then you can get work items across projects. More details, you can refer the document [Query across projects.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/using-queries?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#query-across-projects)

#### Option 2: Users can view all the work items across projects which assign to themselves

If a user want to view all the work items (across projects) assign to himself, then just click the button next to search on the right-top webpage (in New Navigation) to view all the work items "Assign to me".

[image]

Comment: The community request mentioned has been closed. Please up vote a similar request that is under review [Single Dashboard for Multiple Projects](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/single-dashboard-for-multiple-projects/365500)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to achieve some kind of multi-projects multi-teams using a single project in Azure DevOps so in turn you can track more easily work to-do and done. Look at this article: [How to Set Up Multi-Level Hierarchies in VSTS](http://devmanwalking.com/2017/06/12/how-to-set-up-multi-level-hierarchies-in-vsts/).